# How to use Javascript to read file in Rails tmp?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tmp

The way I have it right now is that I use JavaScript to read a file, providing a hard coded path. I tell it to look it `/public`. I'm going to generate a file in the `tmp` directory with Rails, and I want to read it with JavaScript. How can I do this? What is the tmp directory of Rails?

I've tried putting the file into `/tmp` and hard coding JavaScript to read from `/tmp`, but it doesn't load the file.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think browser can access only files inside public folder unless it goes through Rails route. So, you can either change the location of tmp folder or you can create a method in a controller that will read that JS file and send it back to browser (sort of like proxy).